# Print variable a certain number of times on a new line each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, printing, newline

I'd like to take a user inputted number, print the string that number of times each time on a new line, without using a for loop or recursion. It's absolutely mind-boggling cause I can't imagine that's possible

calling print(x * y) would return x y times on the same line and that's not what I want

Comment: `print ((x + '\n') * y)`

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ thanks so much, but how can I do it such that the last line is the last x and not a new line?

Comment: `print (((x + '\n') * y).strip())`